# How to prove that some set is a Borel set

Tags: probability-theory

If $B$ is a borel set, is $B+c$ a borel set for some constant $c$ ? I know that it is not possible to characterize a Borel set.

Comment: You want to express it as the union, intersection and\or complement of Borel sets.

Comment: I assume this is for Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: @coffeebelly : I want to know whether this is true or not ? yes that is the only way to prove.

Comment: @AdamHughes: yes.

Comment: @user148951 in that case see my answer below.

Comment: It's not quite true that "it is not possible to characterize a Borel set".  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You know that the set $B+c$ is the inverse image of the measurable set, $B$, under the continuous function:  $f(x)=x-c$, and since continuous functions are measurable, and the inverse image of a measurable set is measurable, $B+c$ is also measurable.

---

**Note:** there is nothing particularly special about Lebesgue measure here other than it being a [Haar measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure). I only use that the measure is a Haar measure on a locally compact group:  in any such case translation is a continuous operation, so you can get the same result.